# Exact match, then partial match

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called posts that has two columns (entry_id and category_id)

```
entry_id | category_id
52 | 44
55 | 47
58 | 50
55 | 55
58 | 52
53 | 51
58 | 56
61 | 56
```

How can I select all entries that are tagged with category_id 50 AND 56 (exact match) first and then order the rest by a partial match - entries tagged only with category_id = 50, next entries tagged with 56 etc.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4):

You need to aggregate your data by entry and then apply the order conditions:

```
select entry_id
from posts
group by entry_id
order by max(category_id = 50) + max(category_id = 56) desc
```

The expression `max(category_id = 50)` returns `1` if category 50 is in the mix (for the entry) and `0` otherwise.  By adding these two expressions together, you get the number of category matches.

If you care about the order of the singleton matches (as suggested by the question), then do:

```
select entry_id
from posts
group by entry_id
order by max(category_id = 50) + max(category_id = 56) desc,
         max(category_id = 50) desc,
         max(category_id = 56) desc
```

EDIT:

If you store your available categories in a comma delimited list, then you can have the best of all worlds.  You can order by the number of categories matching (first).  You can then use the list to prioritize the categories.  And, you can ensure that all the entities with the same set of categories appear together.  It just takes string manipulation.

The expression:

```
count(distinct (case when find_in_set(category_id, @categories) > 0 then category_id end))
```

will count the number of categories (for an entitY) that are in the list.

The expression:

```
group_concat((case when find_in_set(category_id, @categories) > 0
                   then find_in_set(category_id, @categories)
              end)
```

Will create a string where the elements represent the positions in the string.  So, if you pass in `'a,b,c;` and an entity matches `'b'` and `'c'`, then the string will be `'2,3'`.  If it had all three, then it would be `'1,2,3'`.  This provides what you need for prioritization.

Finally, adding `entity_id` at the end makes the sort stable:

```
order by count(distinct (case when find_in_set(category_id, @categories) > 0 then category_id end)) desc,
         group_concat((case when find_in_set(category_id, @categories) > 0
                            then find_in_set(category_id, @categories)
                       end)
                      order by find_in_set(category_id, @categories)),
         entry_id
```

Comment: Thank you, just a quick question though: If I don't know the exact order the categories are coming out, how would I amend this? Basically the data is being outputted in random orders depending on the page?

Comment: @Daniel . . . Add a final sort in the `order by` clause on `entry_id`.  This will make the sort a stable sort.

Comment: How would this work though if the category_id is coming out dynamically and not in that order? For example in one instance it may be 50 and 56 as above, but in another instance the output may be 44|50|52|56. Basically the entry_id is assigned to multiple and many categories, so if I was getting the value via PHP, how would I dynamically put these values into the query?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, but I am a little confused as to how to put this all together into a query I can use. I have the category_id output string stored in a php variable (47, 50, 56). How would I apply this to the full query you have done above and where? Thank you for your help so much for everything so far. If possible, would you be able to show me the full query I would use, including the select as it is bringing up errors when I try the above

Comment: Hi, here is a pastebin link that hopefully explains it much, much better: http://pastebin.com/uXn13ZjV